# Upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.0 - cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

Updating Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.1.5

When trying to do a operation repository.save(entity) it gives the following error:

```
Caused by: com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGSQLSimpleException: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction
```

We use the org.springframework.data.repositoryCrudRepository interface to perform the operations.

1) `@Transactional(readOnly = false)`, as i understood setting Read-Only mode to false only works as a hint to the sub-layers, how can i check and change the other layers?

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl

    private final Repository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceImpl(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void operation(Entity entity){
    repository.save(entity);
}
```

And Repository is

```
public interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Entity, UUID>{

    @Query("select e from Entity e where lower(u.name) = lower(?1)")
    Entity findByName(String name);

}
```

````
build.gradle
------------

`dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE")
}
`

```runtime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.3.1")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
    compile("com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:5.2.1")
    compile("org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.28")
    compile("net.java.dev.msv:msv-core:2013.6.1")
    compile("com.impossibl.pgjdbc-ng:pgjdbc-ng:0.8.2")
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.6')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.18')
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.0')
    compile('org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:3.1.0')
    compile('org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy:smiley-http-proxy-servlet:1.10')
    compile('com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:2.1.0')
    compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.3.1')
````

### application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver

spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=


spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000

 # Set auto-commit = false, otherwise - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: 
  Clobs require connection to be in manual-commit mode... 


spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false

logging.level.ROOT=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

One important thing is that i added the Auto-Commit to false in Hikari, otherwise it would fail with an exception as it can bee seen in the comment.

Note: In some threads it was suggested to check postgres connection

```
    show default_transaction_read_only;
     default_transaction_read_only 
    -------------------------------
     off

    SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
     pg_is_in_recovery 
    -------------------
     f
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: Hello everytime i try to add the stacktrace it gives formatting code errors, so i am providing as a link meantime, thanks : https://pastebin.com/a60pN4FV

Comment: Upgrading from 1.5 to 2.0 is a biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig step forward. Personally I have given up eventually because of the lack of time to do all the adjustments needed.

Comment: Logs show that there is one transaction getting created and not closed with this statement: no.app.application.security.UserDetailsService.getUserEntity(UserDetailsService.java:65)
Do you have this as read only transaction?
The same thread continues and gets same transaction which is not properly closed during aforementioned method call. Can you share more details on that method?

Comment: If you can share the complete code it will really help.

Answer (score 8):

1. Property `readOnly` is `false` by default, so you should never use `@Transactional(readOnly = false)`, use `@Transactional` instead.
2. When you mark some methods or class with `@Transactional` *Spring* creates a proxy of that class to inject the logic of *Transaction Manager*. It uses a bean that implements interface `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager`
3. In your specific case a bean of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager` will be created.
4. *Spring Boot* is using *Hibernate* as a default *JPA* provider, so eventually all transaction logic will affect *Hibernate*. E.g. `readOnly = true` is used in order to disable "dirty checking" mechanism that performs all UPDATE operations in *Hibernate*.
5. By default, *Spring Transaction Manager* creates a new *Hibernate Session* (new transition) when it calls a method marker with `@Transactional` and no *Session* is attached to the current thread. So all the following calls in the current thread will use the same `Session` (and same transaction). Unless you change the `propagation` property.
6. It all means that **configs for the transaction are set when Spring calls `@Transactional` method the first time and those configs are used for all methods calls in the same thread.** See the code example:

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

@Service
public class ServiceA {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void a() {
        boolean isReadOnly = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly();
        System.out.println(isReadOnly);
    }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class ServiceB {
    private final ServiceA serviceA;

    public ServiceB(ServiceA serviceA) {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void b() {
        serviceA.a();
    }
}
```

- `serviceA.a()` will print `true`
- `serviceB.b()` will print `false`

Comment: Call to b from a is as good as private method call and it is not called through spring proxy so @Transactional attribute marked on b() is not going to take effect. Did you check that txService.b() is really printing true?

Comment: @Ajinkya I updated code example so it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

See [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) about Gradle and add dependency management plugin:

> Spring Boot’s Gradle plugin no longer automatically applies the dependency management plugin. Instead, Spring Boot’s plugin now reacts to the dependency management plugin being applied by importing the correct version of the spring-boot-dependencies BOM. This gives you more control over how and when dependency management is configured.
>
> For most applications applying the dependency management plugin will be sufficient:
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
> apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' // <-- add this to your build.gradle
> ```

Also you can remove `spring.datasource.type`

> If you used spring.datasource.type to force the use of Hikari in a Tomcat-based application, you can now remove that override.

Notice also that minimum Hibernate version is 5.2

Also I see you added `spring-boot-properties-migrator`, note that it should be removed after you finish migration tweaks

> Once you’re done with the migration, please make sure to remove this module from your project’s dependencies.